# How to sum up monthly total in sqlite3

Tags: python, datetime, sqlite

I have this few lines of code here which am able to sum up total value of a `month` but what i want to do is to sum up each `month` and print them.When i change the month value it works alright but i want to sum up total value of each month

```
example:
january =  200
february = 240
march    = 310
....
december = 8764
```

taking year condition into consideration.

***CODE***

```
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM `cash` WHERE strftime('%m', `DATE`) = '10'")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

The table has column `name, date` and `amount` and date is in this format `2019-05-23, 2016-05-30`

```
NAME          DATE         AMOUNT

JOE        2018-01-23       50.00
BEN        2018-01-21       61.00

FRED       2018-02-23       31.00
FRED       2018-02-03       432.00


DAN        2018-03-23       69.00
FRED       2018-03-23       61.00

BRYAN       2018-04-21       432.00
FELIX       2018-04-25       907.00

.......................
......................
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the structure of your table?

Comment: @user2997100 have edited that i want to calculate total value of every month

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you need `GROUP BY`. Something like:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m', date) AS sales_month
     , sum(amount) AS total_sales
FROM sales
GROUP BY sales_month
ORDER BY sales_month;
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ac32f/1)

(You get bonus points for using a date format that sqlite date and time functions understand; too many people use "MM/DD/YYYY' or the like)

Edit: If you have a lot of data and run this frequently, you might want to use a computed index to speed it up:

```
CREATE INDEX sales_idx_monthly ON sales(strftime('%Y-%m', date));
```

Comment: It solve part of what i want what if i want to specify the year i want monthly total

Comment: That's what WHERE clauses are for.

Answer (score 0):

a "group by" instead the where part should work

```
GROUP BY strftime('%Y',`DATE`), strftime('%m',`DATE`)
```

Comment: it doesn't work i want total for `january,february,march` upto `december`

Comment: how is that different from what you get ?

Comment: i have record from january to october but i received only two total